# Multiple Correspondence Analysis: SPSS treats 0 as missing value in indicator matrix

Tags: spss, correspondence-analysis

I have a data set with several ordinal variables. In order to perform a MCA
I've learned that the data must be structured as an indicator matrix.

E.g. I transform the 3-level variable knowledge into there binary coded variables.

```
knowlegde => low knowledge | medium knowledge | high knowledge
1         =>             1                  0                0
2         =>             0                  1                0
3         =>             0                  0                1
```

Now, when I try to run the analysis, SPSS tells me that it treats all 0 as missing data and consequently stops the analysis.

How can I tell SPSS that the 0s are not missing? I haven't found a way to achieve this.

Comment: 1) MCA is odd to use with _ordinal_ variables because MCA is for nominal variables. Consider Categorical PCA (CATPCA) which is more general and can use all types of variables. 2) You don't have to recode categorical variables into indicator dummies. MCA, CATPCA etc will do for you, internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want to use that procedure, you will have to code the variables as 1,2 instead of 0,1.  That odd missing value rule is built into the procedure and several others in the Categories option.